# Return number of appearances in list

Tags: sml

I am trying to create a SML function that takes lost of booleans and returns the number of times that "true" appears in the list.

```
fun truecount(lst) = foldl (fn (x,y) => if x=true then y+1) 0 lst;
```

I feel like I may be on the right path but I just can't quite seem to get it correct. If anyone sees how to do this please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what does your anonymous function

`fn (x,y) => if x=true then y+1`

return when `x` is *not* `true`?

What should it?

For that matter, what *else* do you need in an `if ... then ...` to get it to even compile?

Comment: Okay so you're saying that I am missing an else statement. Should what would it be just "else y"?

Comment: Why don't you tell me.

Comment: Yeah I tried it out and it's all working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: By the way, there's no need to write something like `x = true`, since that's always synonymous with `x`.